# How to detect the current language of a multilanguage joomla website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, joomla

How to detect the current language of a *multilanguage* *joomla* website using *javascript*?

Comment: is there a response object or some sort you can access...I am not sure about joomla...so just thinking if there was a global joomla object on the page..see page source if it can help

Answer (score 3):

Try such way

```
<script>
    window.addEvent('domready',function(){
        var lang = document.getElement('html').getProperty('lang');
        console.log(lang)
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php

            $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
            $lang_code = $lang->getTag();
            $lang_name = $lang->getName(); 

?>
```

In Js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var language_code = "<?php echo $lang_code;?>";
var language_name = "<?php echo $lang_name ;?>";
console.log("Lang Code"+language_code+"Lang Name"+language_name);
</script>
```

Hope this may help you..

Answer (score 2):

```
var lang = document.getElement('html').getProperty('lang');
```

this code won't work on ie depending on your template, you may have some

```
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
```

tags specifying the lang to en.